# Using XML with Android

Tags: android, xml, layout, button

I want to create a set of objects which inherit from some Android View objects. For exemple, I want to create a custom button (which I may call CustomButton) inheriting from Button.
CustomButton has several parameters which Button doesn't have, let's say it contains an int called "start_count", and that a custom methods shows start_count+(the number of press actions).

A Button object is nearly always created using an XML layout. 
I'd like to create my CustomButton exactly the same way, with another attribute called for exemple : android:startCount="3".

I don't really know where to search. Do you happen to have a useful link or advice about this problem ?

Comment: Start out with [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html). The custom attributes are somewhat bad documented, so you have to google a bit around. [Here](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/) is one tutorial i found by searching "android custom attributes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend your class `CustomButton` from the Button class, and add to it whatever you want.

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). You can like change text, functions, or drawables etc with for example `this.setText()`, or `mButton.setText()` (after CustomButton mButton = new... ofcourse)